# Index was out of range error

Tags: c#

I have been looking for the reason why I get this error message for several days now! And I need help to solve this or to improve the code. It's hard to understand why this error happens and find the reason, when it just happens sometimes and not all the time! But my guess is that it has to do with the list and the numbers of items in the lists. It's in the second part of the code where the error event happens. I have also tried to add the objects that I want to remove in a special "to remove list", but why should this not work? Help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
public void CollisionControlMissileHitAsteroid(ContentManager content)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < missilesList.Count(); i++)
    {
        // Stora asteroider
        for (int j = 0; j < asteroidsBigList.Count(); j++)
        {
            if (missilesList.ElementAt(i).Bounds().Intersects(asteroidsBigList.ElementAt(j).Bounds())) // Fel här ??
            {

                for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
                AddNewSmallAsteroidToList(new AsteroidSmall(content, asteroidsBigList.ElementAt(j).Position));
                missilesList.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;

                asteroidsBigList.RemoveAt(j);
                j--;
            }
        }


        if (missilesList.Count() > 0 && asteroidsSmallList.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int k = 0; k < asteroidsSmallList.Count(); k++) 
            {
                if (missilesList.ElementAt(i).Bounds().Intersects(asteroidsSmallList.ElementAt(k).Bounds())) // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR EVENT HAPPENS!
                {
                    missilesList.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                    asteroidsSmallList.RemoveAt(k); 
                    k--;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

EDIT:

Is this where I should place the break? Ask beacause it still happens! I can play for five minutes until it happens!

```
if (missilesList.Count() > 0 && asteroidsSmallList.Count() > 0)
{

    for (int k = 0; k < asteroidsSmallList.Count(); k++) 
    {
        if (missilesList.ElementAt(i).Bounds().Intersects(asteroidsSmallList.ElementAt(k).Bounds())) 
        {
            missilesList.RemoveAt(i); 
            i--;
            asteroidsSmallList.RemoveAt(k);
            k--;
            break; // ???????
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in the debugger?

Comment: Is the use of `Count()` correct? You should use it only for `IEnumerable<T>` that aren't `List`(s)/`Array`(s)...

Comment: The error message was: Index out of range. Must be a non negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: @xanatos: It's *correct* - just not idiomatic. It'll work fine, and won't be O(n) or anything crazy.

Comment: I missed the "()" after the Count! It should be Count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you start off with one missile and two asteroids. The missile (i=0) hits the first asteroid (j=0) - but you're then continuing with i=-1 and j=0. You should be breaking out of the inner loop and continue with the next iteration of the outer loop there instead. After all, you're "done" with the missile - it can't hit any other asteroids, big or small.

(And yes, as per xanatos's comments, it would be more idiomatic to use the `Count` property instead of the `Count()` method.)

Comment: I added the break, but I'm not sure if it's the right place, because it still happens?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in thinking that it's to do with the bounds of the list. I've never come up with a satisfactory way of removing listitems or array elements within a loop other than, as you say, building up a list of indexes and removing them outside of the loop.
Having said that, have you tried going through the list backwards, like -

```
for (int k = asteroidsSmallList.Count() - 1; k >= 0; k--) 
{
    ...
```

Comment: That's right. '.Count' returns number of elements (not counting element Zero) so you should subtract 1 from it if you want to iterate through the items one by one

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is obvious because your code runs in a for loop. In the first for loop you got `i=0`. Read my comments inside

```
for (int i = 0; i < missilesList.Count(); i++)
    {
        // Stora asteroider
        for (int j = 0; j < asteroidsBigList.Count(); j++)
        {
            if (missilesList.ElementAt(i).Bounds().Intersects(asteroidsBigList.ElementAt(j).Bounds())) // Fel här ??
            {

                for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
                    AddNewSmallAsteroidToList(new AsteroidSmall(content, asteroidsBigList.ElementAt(j).Position));
                missilesList.RemoveAt(i);
                // In the first iteration of the outer for loop i=0, so what if the line below is executed
                // you will get negative index Hope this help
                i--;

                asteroidsBigList.RemoveAt(j);
                j--;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmm, but what if I used: if (missileList.Count() > 0) before i--, Then there could never be a -1?! Could that work?

Comment: if (missilesList.ElementAt(i).Bounds().Intersects(asteroidsSmallList.ElementAt(k).Bounds()) // What if i is -1 from previous for loop where you decrements the i and j

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to solve this! Could it ever be -1 if I prevent it from decreasing if the value isn't greater then 0 ?